# Adding Pagination to Link Headers in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, pagination, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Currently in my Rest service I return paged data using the model that follows.

```
public class PagedResults<T>
{
    public List<LinkModel> Links { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    public double TotalPages { get; set; }
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
}
```

This works alright, but I came across the following post.

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#pagination

My curiosity was peaked, it mentions using the HTTP headers to return links and pagination information.  Although the post mentions RFC 5988, I was unable to unravel what that really means?  Was it every actually adopted as a standard of some sort?

The question here is in ASP.Net Web API 2, is there any support for adding pagination information in the link header?  I used intellisense to peruse HTTP response headers and I did not find Links, or anything similar.

I found this post, but it doesn't really answer my question of ease of doing this in Web API 2.

[Link headers vs link elements for RESTful JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742380/link-headers-vs-link-elements-for-restful-json)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check my [post here](http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/implement-resources-pagination-asp-net-web-api/) which shows how to add pagination as "custom" (X-Pagination) header, below is sample code that might help:

```
 public IEnumerable<StudentBaseModel> Get(int page = 0, int pageSize = 10)
{
    IQueryable<Student> query;

    query = TheRepository.GetAllStudentsWithEnrollments().OrderBy(c => c.LastName);

    var totalCount = query.Count();
    var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / pageSize);

    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);
    var prevLink = page > 0 ? urlHelper.Link("Students", new { page = page - 1, pageSize = pageSize }) : "";
    var nextLink = page < totalPages - 1 ? urlHelper.Link("Students", new { page = page + 1, pageSize = pageSize }) : "";

    var paginationHeader = new
    {
        TotalCount = totalCount,
        TotalPages = totalPages,
        PrevPageLink = prevLink,
        NextPageLink = nextLink
    };

    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination",
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));

    var results = query
    .Skip(pageSize * page)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList()
    .Select(s => TheModelFactory.CreateSummary(s));

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I was after.  Just for my clarification though, is X-Pagination a standard header, you say custom header in your answer?  So this is not something that is common enough to have its own dedicated header yet?

Comment: No its custom header, any header starts with X usually is not standard HTTP header.

Comment: would it be better to use link headers? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988#page-6

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh, your link to your post appears to be broken.

Comment: @Spidermain50 I just checked it and it's working, any how you can go to bitoftech.net and get it from the archives.

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh my work must be blocking the site. I will check it out at home. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In .Net MVC adding Link headers is trivial. According to the [IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-5.5) they get separated by comma, so:

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Link", string.Join(",", pagedResult.Links));
```

> Note: that `pagedResult` is in an instance of your `PagedResult<T>` class.

This can be used in conjunction with Taiseer's `X-Pagination` headers above.